# zLib transparent write mode "wT" performance degradation

Tags: linux, performance, io, zlib

I would expect zLib transparent mode ( gzptintf() ) as fast as regular fprintf(). I found zLib gzprintf() with "wT" is 2.5x slower than fprintf(). Is there any workaround on this performance issue?

Details:

I’m using libz.so.1.2.8 on Linux (fedora 22, kernel 4.0.5, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz) to provide output file compress option to my event trace collector. To keep legacy compatibility I need transparent file format writing mode.

As I see, the option “T” in gzopen allow to write files with no compression and no gzip header record.

The problem is in performance. The transparent mode is ~2.5x slower than simple standard fprintf.

Here is quick test result (values are in TSC):

```
    zLib]$ ./zlib_transparent
Performance fprintf vs gzprintf (transparent):
     fprintf 22883026324
zLib transp  62305122876
ratio 2.72277
```

The source for this test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#define NUMITERATIONS 10000000
static double buffer[NUMITERATIONS];

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void){
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

long long test_fprintf(double *buffer){
    long long t = rdtsc();
#ifdef USE_FPRINTF
    double tmp = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen("fprintf_file.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMITERATIONS; ++i) {
        fprintf(file, "[%f:%f]\n", buffer[i], buffer[i] - tmp);
        tmp = buffer[i] + i;
    }
    fclose(file);
#endif
    return rdtsc() - t;
}

long long test_zlib_transparent(double *buffer){
    long long t = rdtsc();
#ifdef USE_ZLIB
    double tmp = 0;
    gzFile file = gzopen("zlib_file.txt.gz", "wT");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMITERATIONS; ++i) {
        gzprintf(file, "[%f:%f]\n", buffer[i], buffer[i] - tmp);
        tmp = buffer[i] + i;
    }
    gzclose(file);
#endif
    return rdtsc() - t;
}


int main(){
    std::cout << "Performance fprintf vs gzprintf (transparent):" << std::endl;
    long long dPrint = test_fprintf(buffer);
    std::cout << "     fprintf " << dPrint << std::endl;

    long long dStream = test_zlib_transparent(buffer);
    std::cout << "zLib transp  " << dStream << std::endl;

    std::cout << "ratio " << double(dStream)/double(dPrint) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build:

```
g++ -g -O3 -DUSE_ZLIB=1 -DUSE_FPRINTF=1 zlib_transparent.cpp -o zlib_transparent –lz
```

Thank you

Sergey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad.  (I wrote `gzprintf()`.)

`write()` is being called too often.  You will get approximately the same performance as zlib if you replace `fprintf()` with `snprintf()` and `write()`.

I will improve this in the next version of zlib.  If you would like to try it, apply [this diff](https://github.com/madler/zlib/commit/95698093f023852ca4365df307c19a1d7cfa3687).  I don't know how it will perform on Linux, but on Mac OS X, `gzprintf()` in transparent mode is now 10% *faster* than `fprintf()`.  (Wasn't expecting that.)

Comment: I guess you are the developer of zlib? In that case it would be better if you could make it clear that it is a bug in zlib code, because I had to read that "my bad" twice plus check you are not the OP to understand it :)

Comment: Yes, I am the zlib developer.  It is not a bug.  zlib works exactly as advertised in this case.  It is an opportunity to improve zlib's performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and patch. If you like I can test your  version (with new code) on Linux (several versions).
I would like to use single gzprintf to produce compressed and non-compressed output in my code. 
Thank you again.
Sergey

Comment: The performance gain confirmed.

Currently the gzprintf() with "wT" has same performance (~1% slower) as standard I\O fprintf() on Linux RHEL 6.5

Tested with Nasa Parallel Benchmark suite (BT, CG, FT, LU, MG, SP) Class E, 1024 ranks (PPN=28) on cluster. File system is Lustre SSD via Infiniband FDR.